# У персонажа не отнимается здоровье при столкновении с игроком

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Делал игру по туториалу чтобы примерно понимать как это работает но что-то пошло не так. Цель - при столкновении с врагом перезагружается уровень и отнимается здоровье. Но выдает что Application.loadlevel устарел, пробовал сделать как советует Visual Studio 2017 - не помогло. Пользуюсь Unity 2018.1.6f1 Personal.

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;//для работы со сценами!

public class Hero : MonoBehaviour {

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator anim;
    int Life = 100;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            pipka();//Jump method
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0)
        {
            anim.GetInteger("Poka, 1");
        }
        else
        {
            Flip();//Поворот героя, когда тот идет в другую сторону
            anim.GetInteger("Poka, 2");//Если игрок стоит, то анимация покоя,а если движется анимация бега
        }
    }
    void OnCollisiomEnter2D(Collision2D shit) {

        if (shit.gameObject.tag == "pipa")//Проверка столкновения
        {
            //Invoke("ReloadLevel",3);//вызов перезагрузки уровня
            Life--;

        }
    }

    void OnGUI(){
        GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 30), "Life =" + Life);
        }



    void ReloadLevel()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);//
    }



    void Flip(){
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0);
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);

    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 12f, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    void pipka()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * 14f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Перевел почти весь код в текст но не получается перевести первые 5 строк. Читал инструкцию.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужен DontDestroyOnLoad объект, на который ты повесишь скрипт с данными, в данном случае со здоровьем. 
Здесь прикол в том, что, когда ты уровень перезагружаешь, у тебя все данные перезаписываются, потому что оно все лежит у тебя в том самом уровне, который ты перезагружаешь.

Вот почитай [здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)